Pi Virtual Keyboard doesn't focus in text box
On a PI 4 I have installed "Matchbox Keyboard" and "Onboard" but can get neither one to focus where I want to write text. I am trying to write something in a browser search bar so I "click" there and that's where the cursor then is. Next I click on the keyboard and the focus goes away from the browser search bar and onto the keyboard. I click again in the search bar where I want to write and the keyboard disappears.
What am I doing wrong ?
I have tried reinstalling and changing settings, nothing has made any difference.

I should have said "touch" on the browser search bar and "touch" on the keyboard, it is a touchscreen rather than a mouse.

I have reinstalled again but this time with 64-bit OS instead of 32-bit as my project had suggested 32 would be better but that project is irrelevant until I get this thing working ! Anyway, still can't type anywhere...
